# What exacly happens when a class constructor calls a setter

Tags: javascript, class, constructor, getter-setter

Hi at this code example i can't fully understand when the **setter** fullname method gets called from the constructor why the constructor does not create also a property **"fullname"** but it just invokes the setter and moves to the next line.

Can someone explain to me what happens in detail it will be much appreciated.

```
class Person {
  constructor(fullname, birthYear) {
    this.fullname = fullname;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
  }          
  set fullname(name) {
    if (name.includes(' ')) this._fullname = name;
    else alert(`${name} is not a full name`);
  }
 
  get fullname() {
    return this._fullname;
  }
}
 
const personObj = new Person('FirstName Lastname', 1999);
console.log(personObj);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `new` keyword creates an object with the prototype of `Person`, then calls the constructor. So by the time the constructor is called, it already has that object, and that object has a pair of setters and getters for `this.fullname`. If you attempt to assign to `this.fullname`, the standard behavior for setters and getters occurs, and the setter will be called. The behavior doesn't get modified due to being inside a constructor function.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor does not create a new property named `fullname` since that property already exists, defined by the getter and setter. However it is not a data property but an accessor property, so it holds no value of it's own.